# Need help isolating styling from global setting for themeing using filter: invert

Tags: css, reactjs, html, react-native

using https://github.com/Heydon/react-theme-switch to introduce a night and day mode to large app that was not initially built with this in mind.

Wondering if there is a method to selectively apply {filter: invert} to only specific elements, or a method to override the filter on such specific elements

like suppose primary theme colour is $primary: #0000ff and I don't want it to invert with everything else?

I did find that i could use something like id="banana" on some elements that I did not want to invert by including it in

`if (this.props.preserveRasters) { this.css += 'img:not([src*=".svg"]), video, [style*="url("], [id*="banana"] { filter: invert(100%) }' }`

Some help would be great